# Grep command with OR logic

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh

I have a directory in which I have numerous files with names like work1, work2, work3, work4 ... workn (where n is any number). I want to only list the files which has `work` as the prefix after that only 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

For example: It should list down `work1` `work2` `work3` `work4` `work5` . So my logic was `ls -al | grep work` but it will list `work6`, `work7` etc too. How do  proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There is no need to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Just use a range expression when calling `ls`:

```
ls -al work[1-5]
```

This will match any file whose name matches the pattern `work[1-5]`. That is, any file whose name is `work1`, ..., `work5`.

Comment: _"There is no need to parse the output of ls."_  <--very important +1.

Comment: Hey hey I appreciate your love but there is no need for balancing downvotes, otherwise this will become too well accepted for a simple answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Try regex:

```
ls | grep -E 'work[1-5]'
```

Comment: Except for file names that contain newlines. Don't use code that works in *most* cases when that code is more complicated than code that works in *all* cases.